# Retrieve header information from exe

Tags: python, header, exe

I was wondering whether it would be possible to write a python script that retrieves header information from an .exe file. I tried googling but didn't really find any results that were usable.

Thanks.

Sept

Answer (score 2):

There is [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/) : *multi-platform Python module to read and work with Portable Executable (aka PE) files. Most of the information in the PE Header is accessible, as well as all the sections, section's information and data.*

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'm almost 2 years and a dollar short!  If you still need to solve this, Michał Niklas was right on point above.  pefile was written for this very purpose. Here is an example from my interactive session:

```
ipython
import pefile
pe = pefile.PE('file.exe')
pe.print_info()
```

The output is too verbose to put up here, but the above gives you all header information from a PE.

Download pefile here: [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to write a Python script to retrieve header information from an XYZ file. Three simple steps:

(1) Find docs for the header part of an XYZ file; read them.

(2) Read the docs for the Python struct module or ctypes module or both.

(3) Write and test the script.

Which step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Basically all parts of it except step 3. I am not new to pytohn but i am new to this kind of programming. Could you maybe offer a short code snippet or the like? A practical example. I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Sept: I can't imagine how a short code snippet could provide a practical example. Besides, you said you weren't having trouble with step 3. If you are serious about developing your skills in this area, here is one of the shortest practical examples: (1) google for docs on the DBF (dbaseIII, Foxpro, etc) format (2) find Raymond Hettinger's dbase3 reading script in the Python Cookbook (3) compare at least the header-reading part of the script with the docs